# Splash do not render the whole page

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, scrapyjs

I like to use scrapy and splash to grabb some data but poorly splash seems not to render the whole --> [page](http://www.asos.com/asos/asos-heavyweight-parka-with-borg-lining-and-faux-fur-trim-in-tobacco/prd/8178095?clr=tobacco&SearchQuery=&cid=2112&gridcolumn=1&gridrow=1&gridsize=4&pge=1&pgesize=72&totalstyles=2661) <--.

The page should look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

So some of the more important information is missing. I already tried to increase the waiting time but this had no positive effect.
Does anyone have an idea what I could do, to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at Splash [FAQ](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly) where common problems with page rendering are discussed. Especially, I've often seen problem with private mode. [Here](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-disable-private-mode) is described how to turn it off. You can check if private mode is the issue in Splash web console, just edit the default LUA script and add

```
splash.private_mode_enabled = false
```