# Splash does not render java script

Tags: javascript, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

My question is closely related to this post: [Splash do not render the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476298/splash-do-not-render-the-whole-page)

I am not able to configure splash in a way that in renders the dynamic part of the following website:

https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/ro/slava-cerchez%C4%83/LRTC/date/2018-8-03?cm_ven=localwx_history

[The page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPQ8J.png)

[But it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csxk0.jpg)

Here is the splash-script:

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(5))
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  splash.private_mode_enabled = false
  splash.indexeddb_enabled = true
  splash.html5_media_enabled = true


  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),


  }
end
```

I already tried to increase waiting time and to disable private mode. I would be very glad if someone could give a hint how to configure splash correctly so that it renders the java script part.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the historical weather data on that site. I was unable to figure out how to get the page to render using Splash. However, using a Seleuium driven browser appears to render the page correctly. This isn't as ideal because you'll actually have to render the page, but it works.

Selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html